# django with jinja2 using model's get_absolute_url definition in template

Tags: django, jinja2

I am using jinja2 as my template engine in Django 1.10. I have a model that has a definition as:

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('apps.web.views.work_detail', kwargs={'year':self.created_at.year,
                                                            'month':self.created_at.strftime("%m"),
                                                            'day':self.created_at.strftime("%d"),
                                                            'slug':self.slug,
                                                           'workId':self.id})
```

and my urls.py has:

```
 url(r'^ardiye/çalışmalar/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+),(?P<workId>\d)/$', work_detail, name='work_detail')
```

when i use my model definition to get the absolute url in my template via `<a href='{{next_work.get_absolute_url() }}' class='directional-menu-prev'>Önceki</a>` i get an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'apps.web.views.work_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'year': 2016, 'slug': 'kksjs', 'month': '09', 'day': '10', 'workId': 2}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is called "work_detail", not "apps.web.views.work_detail". You should use that name in the get_absolute_url method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation of the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function, the first parameter "can be a URL pattern name or the callable view object". So, either import the `work_detail` view function and pass it directly to the `reverse` function (without single quotes), or pass the URL pattern name, which is `'work_detail'`.